# Android Grid with LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to build a grid with some linear layouts.
Unfortunately the buttons inside the "grid" fill all the space and the "grid" isn't always the same size.

```
<ScrollView 
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1"> 
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:gravity="center_horizontal"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

  <ImageView
  android:id="@+id/imageView1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/banner" 
  android:background="#80000000"
  android:contentDescription="@string/about"/>

  <LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   <TextView
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
   android:text="@string/modi1"
   tools:context=".MenuActivity" />
   <TextView
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
   android:text="@string/modi2"
   tools:context=".MenuActivity" />
   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout     
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/szen_diagramm" />
    <Button
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"          
    android:text="@string/szen_countdown" />
   </LinearLayout>
    <Button
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/szen_diagramm" />
    <Button
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"          
    android:text="@string/szen_countdown" />
   </LinearLayout>
    <Button
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/szen_diagramm" />
    <Button
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"          
    android:text="@string/szen_countdown" />
   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

It should look something like 
[this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/23nzqf3m939bq0j/Screenshot.png)
with the buttons centered and at the size they need with the text inside.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: You want to build a grid with a `LinearLayout`? Why? Use a `TableLayout` instead of. Thats the reason of its existence!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableRow>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#80000000"
            android:contentDescription="ImageView"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:src="@drawable/banner" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="modi1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="modi2" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="szen_diagramm" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="szen_countdown" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="szen_diagramm" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="szen_countdown" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="szen_diagramm" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="szen_countdown" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

[image]
this is how it shows to me

Comment: Hi, thanks, I used this code, but the buttons are still full width and vertically not correct :( [see screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g42dpuyzvad9k09/Screenshot_2012-08-09-13-17-24.png)

Comment: can u explain how exactly u want the button?

Comment: just like a grid...horizontally same height and the buttonwidth just as wide as the buttontext, not the whole grid. if u need any further explanation i can draw you a picture, but i'm at work now? so this is a bit difficult...in your example: if you change the buttontext to something more short like "abc" the buttonwidth still stays the same and if i change it to something more long like "abc abc abc abc abc abc" the buttons are not horizontally centered with the other side

Comment: for the buttons you can use layout_width = "wrap_content", and for the layout you are saying that it should be like grid having same horizontal width,but the buttons within it should be the width of the text.

Comment: have u found the solution u were looking for??

Answer (score 1):

Remove the android:layout_weight="1" to avoid the button filling all the space.

You should try using a TableLayout and several TableRow to replace your LinearLayouts containing the buttons, thus creating a well formated grid

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. all the layout_weights, or just in the table, table row, textview or button? can't figure it out -.-

Comment: The TextView weight should be enough.
You should use the visual editor for Android layouts of Eclipse and make quick tests with the different parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, solved inserting a LinearLayout in TableRow. Have a look to the posted xml code and verify if it fits your requirements.

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/table_row_padding_top" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageButton
                android:contentDescription="@string/str_phone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/icon_phone" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/str_phone"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/icon_car"
                android:contentDescription="@string/str_car" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/str_car"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

</TableRow>
```